# How can I preserve new lines in an AngularJS partial?

Tags: angularjs

Within an AngularJS partial I am looping over a list of entries as follows:

```
<ul class="entries">
    <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
        <strong>{{ entry.title }}</strong>
        <p>{{ entry.content }}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The content of `{{entry.content}}` have some linebreaks which are ignored by AngularJS. How can I make it preserve the linebreaks?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

It is just basic HTML. AngularJS won't change anything about that. You could use a `pre` tag instead:

```
<pre>{{ entry.content }}</pre>
```

Or use CSS:

```
p .content {white-space: pre}

...

<p class='content'>{{ entry.content }}</p>
```

If `entry.content` contains HTML code, you could use `ng-bind-html`:

```
<p ng-bind-html="entry.content"></p>
```

Don't forget to include [ngSanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize):

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Comment: Yeah, For the time being i am indeed using a `<pre>` tag but I thought there would be an easy to use filter available for angular which now i  doubt. Something like `{{entry.content | pre}}` or `{{entry.content | html}}`

Comment: @Amyth   angular will only treat it as text as does browser. Anything beyond that is up to you

Comment: For the CSS `white-space` parameter, use `pre-wrap` instead of `pre`. Otherwise long sentences won't be automatically broken into newlines.

Comment: Don't forget to install ngSanitize to your module! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Answer (score 35):

I make filters

```
// filters js
myApp.filter("nl2br", function($filter) {
 return function(data) {
   if (!data) return data;
   return data.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
 };
});
```

then

```
// view
<div ng-bind-html="article.description | nl2br"></div>
```

Comment: Amazing - so simple yet awesome!

Comment: \r?\n would probably be more appropriate. Otherwise you leave a sad \r in place for Windows systems.

Answer (score 12):

I fix it by adding `pre-line`:

```
<style>
    pre{
        white-space: pre-line;
    }
</style>
My data:
 <pre>{{feedback.Content}}<pre>
```

Answer (score 12):

```
// AngularJS filter
angular.module('app').filter('newline', function($sce) {
    return function(text) {
        text = text.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    }
});

// HTML
<span ng-bind-html="someText | newline"></span>
```