# Preserve line breaks in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449325/how-can-i-preserve-new-lines-in-an-angular-partial) SO question.

My code instead of `ng-bind="item.desc"` uses `{{item.desc}}` because I have a `ng-repeat` before.

So my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{item.description}}
</div>
```

The item description contains `\n` for newlines which are not rendered.

How can the `{{item.description}}` display the newlines easily assuming that I have the `ng-repeat` above?

Comment: Put it in a <pre> tag?

Comment: By styling the wrapper `div` with `style="white-space:pre-wrap;"`.

Comment: @Stewie 's comment works perfectly for me (AngularJS 1.2.18), it explicitly shows how to style the individual element (as opposed to pilau's and Paul Weber's solution) and no need to change the styles of the <pre> tag as others proposed.

Comment: You are right, I assumed that everyone knows how to use basic css and apply a class to an element. If Stewie had posted his comment as an answer it would have been better for him. Though it seems as if he has enough points ...

Comment: I agree, @Stewie  definitely should have formatted his comment as an answer. It fixed my issue perfectly.

Comment: @Stewie your the best :+1: that is exactly what should be done with \n but you'll have to be careful where you use it :-).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i preserve new lines in an angular partial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449325/how-can-i-preserve-new-lines-in-an-angular-partial)

Comment: @Matsemann as you can see I start my question with the fact that I had see the possible duplicate and hadn't solved my answer :)

Comment: Make sure you're not using a <p> tag, this will limit the newline to 1max.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Based on @pilau s answer - but with an improvement that even the accepted answer does not have.

```
<div class="angular-with-newlines" ng-repeat="item in items">
   {{item.description}}
</div>

/* in the css file or in a style block */
.angular-with-newlines {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

This will use newlines and whitespace as given, but also break content at the content boundaries. More information about the white-space property can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

If you want to break on newlines, but also not collapse multiple spaces or white space preceeding the text (to render code or something), you can use:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Nice comparison of the different rendering modes: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/white-space.html

Comment: Best solution here IMO, as it doesn't restyle to a mono-spaced font like pre.

Comment: Watch the white-space preceding the text, that will be preserved.

Comment: Since you brought it up wouldn't be `pre-line` the preferred one? It's closer to the way HTML usually renders the the text contents of its nodes and still preservers the newlines.

Comment: Hmm... you are right, pre-line is the better solution, after I am not sure anymore why I choose pre-wrap instead of pre-line. Maybe the browser support for pre-line is not as good? But I will add this to the answer...
Here is a comparison of the renderings: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/white-space.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! `pre-line` is the way to go. Thanks Paul!

Comment: Don't forget the prefixes: 
      white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Firefox */
      white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera mini */
      white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
(http://caniuse.com/#search=pre-wrap)

Answer (score 126):

Try:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <pre>{{item.description}}</pre>
</div>
```

The `<pre>` wrapper will print text with `\n` as text

also if you print the json, for better look use `json` filter, like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <pre>{{item.description|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

---

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/apt588r0/)</kbd>

I agree with `@Paul Weber` that `white-space: pre-wrap;` is better approach, anyways using `<pre>` - the quick way mostly for debug some stuff (if you don't want to waste time on styling)

Comment: The item.description is text which has the `\n` in areas that I do not know, not at the end. I think I need the `pre` based on your edit.

Comment: A lot of times, a <pre> tag isn't a good solution since it transforms the text into courier and breaks the style of the page. The style="white-space:pre-wrap;" solution seems to be a better solution (at least for my situation)

Comment: @CF_HoneyBadger well, for you `@pilau`'s answer is proper one but it doesn't mean that mine is wrong and therefore i got downvoted

Comment: I tried converting all `\n`'s over to `<br/>`'s and then of course these tags weren't being rendered as HTML markup...after all this converting found your `style` solution and this is an incredible help and simplification...now I don't have to keep converting around all my backend data and just make a few changes in the View...You deserve +1000!

Comment: This works for code, but not for showing messages to users for example. I think Paul's answer is the correct one

Answer (score 63):

It's so simple with CSS (it works, I swear).

```
.angular-with-newlines {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

- Look ma! No extra HTML tags!

Comment: @pilau I wanna wrap the text if it contains comma(,) not white space how can I do this?

Comment: @shylendra my solution doesn't wrap text, it makes it behave as if it were in a `pre` tag. Perhaps open another question? Or maybe I missed your point?

Comment: I was wondering about the browser compability. According to this chart, it seems to work in all major browsers. It is a lot less hassle than replacing newlines with br tags. Thanks! Just pay attention to format the code so it contains no spaces, they will show up of course.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: Might be even better to use white-space: pre-wrap, else the content will never wrap.

Answer (score 17):

With CSS this can be achieve easily.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<span style="white-space:pre-wrap;"> {{item.description}}</span>
</div>
```

Or a CSS class can be created for this purpose and can be used from external CSS file

Answer (score 2):

Well it depends, if you want to bind datas, there shouldn't be any formatting in it, otherwise you can `bind-html` and do `description.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>')`
not sure it's what you want though.

Answer (score 1):

the css solution works, however you do not really get control on the styling. In my case I wanted a bit more space after the line break. Here is a directive I created to handle this (typescript):

```ts
function preDirective(): angular.IDirective {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        priority: 450,
        link: (scope, el, attr, ctrl) => {
            scope.$watch(
                () => el[0].innerHTML,
                (newVal) => {
                    let lineBreakIndex = newVal.indexOf('\n');
                    if (lineBreakIndex > -1 && lineBreakIndex !== newVal.length - 1 && newVal.substr(lineBreakIndex + 1, 4) != '</p>') {
                        let newHtml = `<p>${replaceAll(el[0].innerHTML, '\n\n', '\n').split('\n').join('</p><p>')}</p>`;
                        el[0].innerHTML = newHtml;
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    };

    function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
        return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
    }

    function escapeRegExp(str) {
        return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    }
}

angular.module('app').directive('pre', preDirective);
```

Use:

```
<div class="pre">{{item.description}}</div>
```

All it does is wraps each part of the text in to a `<p>` tag.
After that you can style it however you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your styles, this works for me

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

By this text in `<textarea>`can be display as it's in there with spaces and line brakes

**HTML**

```
   <p class="text-style">{{product?.description}}</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-style{
    white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would either use the `<pre>` tag or use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe (use ng-bind-html if you are using 1.2+) after using `.replace()` to change `/n` to `<br />`

Comment: `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Just use the css style "white-space: pre-wrap" and you should be good to go. I've had the same issue where I need to handle error messages for which the line breaks and white spaces are really particular. I just added this inline where I was binding the data and it works like Charm!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to you. I'm not that keen on the other answers here because they don't really allow you to style the newline behaviour very easily. I'm not sure if you have control over the original data, but the solution I adopted was to switch "items" from being an array of strings to being an array of arrays, where each item in the second array contained a line of text. That way you can do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <p ng-repeat="para in item.description">
     {{para}}
  </p>
</div>
```

This way you can apply classes to the paragraphs and style them nicely with CSS.