# Textarea linebreaks not showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, unicode, textarea

I'm building a inbox chat app in angularjs. Users type in their message in a textarea and their messages gets saved into the db.  They can press enter while writing in the textarea to create line breaks (for long messages).

However when I retrieve the messages, all of the line breaks just show as single spaces.  I cannot use 
 because the data I'm retrieving is in angularjs' interpolation brackets    {{messageinfo.message}}.

How do I show the linebreaks a user types in?

Thanks

EDIT:

Answer solved here.

[Preserve line breaks in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684708/preserve-line-breaks-in-angularjs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserve line breaks in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684708/preserve-line-breaks-in-angularjs)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, and does not work in this case, because textareas must be bound with ng-model and don't support ng-bind-html.  There is nowhere to put <pre> tags.

@user1424508, how did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is linebreaks in textareas aren't the same as html tags (`\n` vs `<br />`)

run a replace on it and wallah

```
replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Comment: i did that. That just makes all the spaces turn into <br/> text on the screen. For example if I wrote in the textarea hi bye it would output hi<br/>bye on the screen