# Textarea loosing linebreaks bound with ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I've  a textarea which gives the user to add comments.

```
<li ng-repeat="assesment in items">
    <textarea type="text" ng-model="assesment.currentComment" class="form-control input-sm" ng-enter="addComment(assesment)" ng-blur="setNewCommentEdit(true)" placeholder="Comment..." style="resize:vertical" />
</li>
```

Now when the user edits the text saves and reload the page all linebreaks are gone.
The linebreaks are stored correctly in the database
What am I doing wrong ?

I also tried to wrap the textarea in a `<pre>` tag like desribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684708/preserve-line-breaks-in-angularjs) but that did not help

Comment: Can you explain more as to why you say `they're gone`? Do you mean they don't show up again in the textarea, or when you display them?

Comment: Yeah sorry i wasn't exact there. they aren't just showing up. i'll attach a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="assesment in items">
<textarea type="text" ng-model="assesment.currentComment" class="form-control input-sm" ng-enter="addComment(assesment)" ng-blur="setNewCommentEdit(true)" placeholder="Comment..." style="resize:vertical">   <pre>{{assesment.currentComment}}</pre>   </textarea>
```

I hope it'd work.