# Adding Newline in HTML w/ AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, newline

I'm trying to get AngularJS and/or HTML to print out the following on 2 separate lines:

```
FOO
BAR
```

But my following HTML and JS are showing it on the same line despite my newline `\n`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{name}}!
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'FOO \n BAR';
}
```

Is this possible?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQsV5/3/)

Comment: thanks, Casey. So a `filter` is my only option then... I was hoping it'd be less work.

Comment: A filter is kinda useless... Just inject some HTML and use the ng-bind-html directive.

Comment: The question is incorrectly marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question. 
By using the CSS white-space property, you can display newline characters without adding any HTML tags. <p>, <br/>  or <pre>

Comment: This should be a duplicate of [Preserve line breaks in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684708/preserve-line-breaks-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a `<br>` :

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.name = 'FOO <br> BAR';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span class="name" ng-bind-html-unsafe="name"></span>!
</div>
```

More doc about the ng-bind-html directive : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: hmm - that didn't work for me -http://jsfiddle.net/rQsV5/8/. why's there no HTML rendering?

Comment: Made a mistake, there it works : http://jsfiddle.net/rQsV5/14/

Comment: You need to use ng-bind-html-unsafe, or you can use the ngSanitize module to trust all your HTML injection.

Comment: Just adding my two cents. For me only worked with ng-bind-html. I'm using angular 1.5.9 version.

Answer (score -1):

In HTML all line break, tab and space are ignored.
If you want to insert a new line. use `<br/>` instead

Comment: not true in `<textaraea>` or `<pre>`

Comment: Not right. Angular expression ignore newline character and trims white spaces  by default. Refer answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695414/why-white-space-are-getting-ignored-in-angularjs-application