# AngularJs render only <br />

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, xss

I have a scenario. I have a comment box for the users where they can put comments with new line like:

```
This is my comment.
Part of comment in new line
```

I am saving in database as :

```
model.Description = model.Comment.Replace("\n", "<br />");
//Insert into DB
```

Now while showing it on AngularJs View, it is showing something like:

```
This is my comment. <br /> Part of comment in new line
```

**My html : **

```
<style>
    .angular-with-newlines {
        white-space: pre;
    }
</style>

<div class="ads-details-info col-md-8 angular-with-newlines">
    {{comment}}
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
123123123123 \n 123123123123 <br /> 123123123123 \\n
```

I want to render `<br />` as new line. I know there are some solutions available like: `trustAsHtml` and `ng-bind-html`. But then it becomes vulnerable to `XSS` attack. Which I don't want. I want to allow only some selected tags. Is there any solution available?

I have seen [Preserve line breaks in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684708/preserve-line-breaks-in-angularjs) .  But solutions did not work for me. I don't want comment to be rendered as code and white-space: pre; did not work for me.

Comment: I have seen this solution as well. And it is not the solution in my case. FYI <pre> did not work. It will start showing as code. I don't want to show comment as code.

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate is not very good. Read the other answers.

Comment: I have tried all the solution given in that post. Nothing worked. Even white-space: pre-wrap; did not work.

Comment: I very much doubt that. Did you realize that you shouldn't replace newlines if you use `pre-wrap`?

Comment: Yes I replaced the <br /> with \n but did not work. \n is rendered as it is.

Comment: Then you actually replaced it with `"\\n"`. It is simply not possible to display the newline character as `\n` in HTML.

Comment: Nothing is working. Tried <br /> , \n, \\n ..

Comment: Well, good luck solving it on your own. Without seeing code it's impossible to help.

Comment: @Juhana Edited my question.

Comment: As I said, if you see a \n in the output, you don't actually have a newline character there. http://jsfiddle.net/ryavmpy0/ You'll have to show your **actual** code and your **actual** values. And before you do that, please make sure that it really replicates your problem.

Comment: I created new data and it started working. But why there is extra space on the start?

Comment: You can vote to reopen your own question. Click the "reopen" link below.

Comment: The extra space comes from the space that's in the HTML. You'll have to remove all spacing between the tags and the content. http://jsfiddle.net/ryavmpy0/7/

Comment: @Juhana That works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use with ng-bind-html like this, then `<br/>` will be rendered as html expression

```
<div ng-bind-html="expression" ></div>
```

Comment: Yes I know but then it become vulnerable to XSS attack. So I am not going to use it.

Comment: @UsmanKhalid You can make it safe with sanitize : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml