# convert new line /n to a line break in angular

Tags: css, angularjs, whitespace, angular-filters, linefeed

I have a string which contain new line character /n. Trying to display

the string. Instead of taking the /n as new line, it displays '/n' as text.

```
   $scope.myOutput = " Hello /n"

    {{ myOutput | textFormat }}
```

Required -> Hello (on html page)

Tried :

```
 app.filter('textFormat', function() {
    return function(x) {
      return x.replace(/\\n/g, '<br/>');
   }
```

Tried css styles like white-space: pre;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular - create a new line on HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410095/angular-create-a-new-line-on-html)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This does not replace it, but you can use the CSS attribute `white-space: pre-line;` to render the \n in the browser:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div>Foo
   Bar
       Baz     Foo
     Bar
 


     
  Baz
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

in Angular you can easy convert text to the original format by entering it like so:

component:

```
this.myText = 'This is line one\nThis is line 2\nAnd here is 3'
```

html:

```
<div [innerText]='myText'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - rewrite your filter next way:

```
.filter('textFormat', function() {
    return function (x) {
      return x.replace(new RegExp('\/n', 'g'), '<br/>');
    }
 })
```

2 - in your html you should use the next syntax:

```
<span ng-bind-html="myOutput | textFormat"></span>
```

Where `myOutput` is `$scope.myOutput = ' Hello /n'`