# How to display newline in Angular Template?

Tags: angular

I have a angular page which has a popup, it uses below code as the content of the popup:

```
<div class="xs-12 form-group">
    <div class="no-overflow" *ngIf="detail.Status; else empty">{{detail.Status}}</div>
</div>
```

Now, detail.Status has some newline (\r\n) in it, and I want to show the newline on the page. How to do it?

I tried to replace \r\n with html code for new line, but it shows the code as text directly, not as html.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50814120/4427731

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
String.fromCharCode(10);
```

with CSS

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Here si working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Nxja/3xtcqdej/1/