# Add new line to string in interpolation binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, binding, interpolation

How can I add a new line to string:

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
       {{ getLastAction(activity) }}
 </div>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.getLastAction= function (activity) {
    if (activity) {
        let desc= activity.Desc;
        let first= activity.First;

        let res=  desc+ '<br>' + first;
        return res;
    }
}
```

I tried to put `<br>` and \n but neither worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve line breaks in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684708/preserve-line-breaks-in-angularjs)

Comment: try `<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8" [innerHTML]="getLastAction(activity)">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ng-bind-html directive.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
       <span class="test" ng-bind-html="test"></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.getLastAction= function (activity) {
    if (activity) {
        let desc= activity.Desc;
        let first= activity.First;

        let res=  desc+ '<br>' + first;
        $scope.test = res;
    }
}
```