# Is there a way to get newlines into JSX strings so that they display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jsx

So I am wanting a single string to display over multiple lines, something like this:

```
const str = "Hi\n\there\nBob"
let jsxElement = (<div>{str}</div>)
```

Should display `jsxElement` like this:

```
Hi
there
Bob
```

I have tried `\n` and `\r\n` and `&nbsp` and `<br>` and `<br />`. Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing to do with JSX, you need to fix this with CSS - [just like in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19684708/1048572)

Comment: This worked really neatly thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `<React.Fragment>` like this:

```
  render() {
    const test = "Hi\n\there\nBob";
    return (
      <div>
        {test.split('\n').map((item, index, arr) => {
            return <React.Fragment>
              {item}{index < arr.length - 1 && <br/>}
            </React.Fragment>
        })}       
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot set insert string containing `html` directly instead you will have you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attibute to which you want to append html as string

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:"Line1</br>Line2</br>Line3"}}></div>
```

Second method to do this is to you use this function

```
  appendMiltilineString = (str) => {
    str = str.split('\n')
    return (<>
        {str.map(line=>
        (<>
            {line}<br></br>
        </>))}
      </>)
  }
 {this.appendMiltilineString('Line1\nLine2\nLine3')}
```

Answer (score -1):

\n will not work when you put it in div.I see that you want individual word to be displayed in each line. One way i will do it is split the string with **space(" ")** and map the resultant array. Something like this.

```
  let splitArray = str.split(" ");
  splitArray.map( (s) => (
          <div>{s}</div>
 ))
```

you can also use `<Fragment>` if you don't like multiple divs to be generated.