# wrapping text in an angular interpolated binding

Tags: css, angular

I'd like to do something like this, where I'm trying to keep the line breaks that I have in the data.

```
<div>    
   <p> {{outputline}} </p>
</div>
```

where outputline is `hello\r\nworld` or `hello<br>world`

Both of which I've tried.  I can do it in a more complex way with outputline1, outputline2, etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserve line breaks in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684708/preserve-line-breaks-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<p [innerHTML]="outputline"></p>`

Answer (score -1):

For hello\r\nworld, you can add

```
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

in you css, or <pre> instead of <p> in your template.