# JavaScript: Line break not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have several string variables:

```
var products = [
    {
        name: 'Product_1',
        templateUrl: 'product_1'
    },
    {
        name: 'Product_2',
        templateUrl: 'product_2'
    },
    {
        name: 'Product_3',
        templateUrl: 'product_3'
    },
    {
        name: 'Product_4 \n with extras',
        templateUrl: 'product_4'
    }
];
```

As you can see in product 4 i added a linebrea `name: 'Product_4 \n with extras',`

when i open up my html page:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="product in products" ui-sref="app.{{product.templateUrl}}" >
        {{product.name}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

There is no line break. the output is:

```
Product_1
Product_2
Product_3
Product_4 with extras
```

but it should be:

```
Product_1
Product_2
Product_3
Product_4 
with extras
```

Why isnt the line break working?

```
ng-bind-html="product.name"
```

does not work as intented. As i mentioned i want the result to be:

```
Product_4
with extras
```

but with `ng-bind-html="product.name"` and `Product_4 <br /> with extras` the result is:

```
Prodcut 4


with extras
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript. In HTML whitespace such as `\n` is usually ignored.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i preserve new lines in an angular partial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449325/how-can-i-preserve-new-lines-in-an-angular-partial)

Comment: Also replacing `\n` with `<br />` won't work straightforward.That's because `ng-bind="suff"` - what `{{stuff}}` gets turned into - does not bind HTML. You need to use `ng-bind-html` explicitly. You'll have troubles with `$sce` too then.

Comment: `ng-bind="suff"` definetely does something but not a simple line break. there now is a huuuuugge gap between those words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ngBindHtml` tag in AngularJS and `ngSanitize` in order to render HTML from your scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

You need to set the variable with html like this `var myVar = "Hello<br/>World!";`

And then render your view with this
`<p ng-bind-html="myVar"></p>`

This will output rendered HTML instead of raw text.

```
var products = [
    {
        name: 'Product_1',
        templateUrl: 'product_1'
    },
    {
        name: 'Product_2',
        templateUrl: 'product_2'
    },
    {
        name: 'Product_3',
        templateUrl: 'product_3'
    },
    {
        name: 'Product_4 <br/> with extras',
        templateUrl: 'product_4'
    }
];
```

HTML

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="product in products" ui-sref="app.{{product.templateUrl}}" >
        <p ng-bind-html="product.name"></p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Of course you can use other tags than `p`

The problem you tell us about the multiple break lines, may be related to CSS because `<br/>` will output exactly what you want, see this example

https://jsfiddle.net/8019ymgj/1/

Comment: What's `{%raw%}`? No such thing in AngularJS.

Comment: no. result is: `{%raw%} Product_4 <br/> with extras {%endraw%}`

Comment: Sorry I've messed up with two different questions and answered here the other one, let me update my answer.

Comment: yes. but see my edit pls. the result is not as i want it to be.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using jQuery, try

```
$("#doWhatNow").html("product 4 <br> with extras")
```

Comment: Never, ever, do it with jQuery in angular (not my downvote either). Edit : you should use ``<br/>``